# Toolbar not showing in the layout editor of Android Studio 3.6.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-layout-editor

After updating android studio to 3.6.1 Toolbar not showing in the layout editor.

It's showing like this..
[image]

But it should be like this.

[image]

Number **3** Option not showing in my case.

Comment: Hi check updated answer it may help you. go to view--> Tool Windows--> preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok as far as I think there's no option to show or hide the specific toolbar you are mentioning in your question. Android Studio seems to be doing it by default.

The issue in your case is that android studio will show the toolbar if you open the any layout.xml inside the `layout` folder in your `res` folder. Try opening an xml inside `layout` it should be showing this by default.

As visible from your screenshot you have opened an xml from `menu` folder. The layout editor in this case only shows the contents in your `main_menu.xml` like a dropdown list etc. and not how it appears in the actual layout if I am not wrong.

If this menu is include in some layout's xml file in the `layout` folder try opening that to see the contents and the toolbar you mentioned.

See if this works for you